# JS Data object is not iterable in console

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently I'm trying to call a function with a data response from an ajax call, and I'm getting that my constant stores is not iterable. My AJAX call looks like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "<?php echo JURI::base() . "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=hunter_maps_dev&method=getStoresByZip&zip="?>"  +zip+ "&format=json",
                         datatype : "application/json",
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log('success');
                            const stores = data;
                            console.log(stores);
                            buildLocationList(stores);

                        },

...

 function buildLocationList({ features }) {
    for (const { properties } of features) {

    }
 }
```

and I'm logging it to the console.

I'm getting this for the data in the console: `data: "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-104.9981929\",\"39.7164275\"]},\"properties\":{\"store`

and this is the mock I was previously using:

```
const stores = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [
      {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
          'type': 'Point',
          'coordinates': [-77.034084142948, 38.909671288923]
        },
        'properties': {
          'storeImage' : 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
          'storeName' : 'Test Store',
          'phoneFormatted': '(202) 234-7777',
          'phone': '2022347336',
          'address': '1471 P St NW',
          'city': 'Washington   DC',
          'country': 'United States',
          'crossStreet': 'at 15th St NW',
          'postalCode': '20005',
          'state': 'D.C.'
        }
      },
    ]
  };
```

What is missing for me to get this to match the mock format so that it's iterable?

UPDATE: Full response currently

`{"success":true,"message":null,"messages":null,"data":"{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-104.9981929\",\"39.7164275\"]},\"properties\":{\"storeImage\":\"1542820219karmalogo2-Copy.png\",\"storeName\":\"Karmaceuticals\",\"phoneFormatted\":\"303-765-2762\",\"address\":\"4 S Santa Fe Drive\",\"city\":\"Denver\",\"country\":\"USA\",\"postalCode\":\"80223\",\"state\":\"Colorado\"}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-104.8526653\",\"39.7861717\"]},\"properties\":{\"storeImage\":\"1438052652medicineman_logo_web.jpg\",\"storeName\":\"Medicine Man - Denver\",\"phoneFormatted\":\"303-373-0752\",\"address\":\"4750 Nome St.\",\"city\":\"Denver\",\"country\":\"Denver\",\"postalCode\":\"80239\",\"state\":\"Colorado\"}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-105.0135439\",\"39.7206576\"]},\"properties\":{\"storeImage\":\"1455044497CannaBoticaOrange.png\",\"storeName\":\"CannaBotica \",\"phoneFormatted\":\"303-777-1550\",\"address\":\"219 Vallejo st.\",\"city\":\"Denver\",\"country\":\"United States\",\"postalCode\":\"80223\",\"state\":\"Colorado\"}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-104.8664385\",\"39.6817321\"]},\"properties\":{\"storeImage\":\"1458987858medicine-man-aurora.jpg\",\"storeName\":\"Medicine Man - Aurora\",\"phoneFormatted\":\"303-923-3825\",\"address\":\"1901 S Havana Street\",\"city\":\"Aurora\",\"country\":\"\",\"postalCode\":\"80014\",\"state\":\"Colorado\"}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-116.905029\",\"33.0433045\"]},\"properties\":{\"storeImage\":\"1479714765showgrow-logo.jpg\",\"storeName\":\"Showgrow - Ramona\",\"phoneFormatted\":\"760-687-9700\",\"address\":\"736 Montecito Way\",\"city\":\"Ramona\",\"country\":\"United States\",\"postalCode\":\"92065\",\"state\":\"California\"}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-117.8467455\",\"33.7201192\"]},\"properties\":{\"storeImage\":\"1479715612showgrow-logo.jpg\",\"storeName\":\"Showgrow -Santa Ana\",\"phoneFormatted\":\"949-565-4769\",\"address\":\"1625 E St Gertrude Pl\",\"city\":\"Santa Ana\",\"country\":\"United States\",\"postalCode\":\"92705\",\"state\":\"California\"}}]}"}`

Comment: It looks like `stores` is a string containing JSON, but not an actual JSON object.

Comment: just put stores into parser: let obj = JSON.parse(stores); and you will get JSON object from string

Comment: the question is he is already using `application/json` in datatype why its not been parsed then

Comment: @AmirRahman because the response is an *object* containing *JSON*. The `data` value ends up being double encoded.

Comment: @VLAZ i was also thinking its a double encoded issue i never used jquery ajax so i thought it might be some jquery ajax issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON string to convert it to an object:

```js
buildLocationList(JSON.parse(stores));
```

Comment: Ok I tried this and now I'm getting ```VM15237:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1```

Comment: @Geoff_S Are you sure the JSON is valid? Can you post the full response?

Comment: I believe so, you can see the full reswponse in my update. I know that the same result works if I just echo it into the constant via PHP echo from another method. It's just when it comes back through AJAX

Comment: @Geoff_S Weird... that response appears to be an object. Your original code (without my suggestion) should work then.

Comment: So if I echo out via PHP (with the json_encode version from my php file) it works fine. However, if I get the exact same result from my php file via com_ajax through joomla, it comes back this way and even parsing it seems to not help. I wonder if I should convert it in the php file differently

Comment: I added s check to stores just to make sure and it definitely comes back as an object dataType

Comment: @Geoff_S OK. Then remove the `JSON.parse` part and it should work.

Comment: It goes back to being not iterable now....I've never been so confused haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237472/discussion-between-spectric-and-geoff-s).